# Getting the nth occurence of a word between delimiters in MS Query

Tags: ms-query

Is there a way to find a word between delimiters in Microsoft Query? For example find "this", which is the 3rd word between underscores in "what_could_this_be".

For reference, in MySQL I would have done it by `SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(field, ' ', 3), ' ', -1)`.

Comment: For those who might not know MS-Query, you might want to give a link to the available string functions.

Comment: Well, there's no explicit documentation, but it seems to follow [Access (in this case text) Expressions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Expressions-684295d0-97c2-443c-8e0a-8c6b635bec56#ID0EAABAAA=Text).